# Interpolate an IP address URL in an ingress route in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a Traefik ingress route configured to forward external traffic from `baz.[IP address].sslip.io` to a service named `baz-service`.

It is configured like this:

/charts/templates/my-app.yaml

```
...
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host("baz.{{ .Values.ipAddress }}.sslip.io")
    services:
    - name: baz-service
      port: 5000
...
```

I have in the values:

charts/values.yaml

```
api:
   ... # Numerous variables that ARE working and interpolating the template correctly
  "ipAddress": "123.123.123.123"
...
```

When I attempt to install this, helm parses the host as `baz..sslip.io`

I have also tried:

```
api:
  "ipAddress": 123.123.123.123
...
```

I have tried creating various functions in in templates/_helpers.tpl and piping the value to the function `{{ .Values.ipAddress | somefunction }}`. Unfortunately I didn't preserve exactly what I id there, as this was in an ephemeral machien, not in the project's repo.

Does anyone know how to make Helm interpolate this as baz.123.123.123.123.sslip.io or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `ipAddress` setting is inside a `api` setting, and this also needs to be in the template code; `{{ .Values.api.ipAddress }}`.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thanks! This was the issue. The mystery is how everything else BUT this one was  interpolating and not this one, when they were all under .Values.api. ... In any case, the problem was solved. Sorry for the slow reply.